# Javascript object create nested elements through dot notation

Tags: javascript

How do I create nested elements in Javascript object through dot notation only? like

```
a= {};
a.b = 100; //is valid
a.x.y = 200; //is invalid?
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the question

Comment: Thanks! I removed the json tag.

Comment: Also, sorry if I was harsh, the intention was only to be instructive. Calling an object literal "json" is a common misconception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 3rd is invalid as `a.x` is undefined.

And you are trying to set a value to a `undefined property`

```
a= {};
a.b = 100; //is valid

a.x = {}; 
a.x.y = 200; // This works
```

Comment: Yes this works, unfortunately I have to nest 7 ~ 10 objects. I can accomplish it using a["x.y....."] but it is discouraged where I work, due to some code style checks.

Comment: you can use a literal object notation like this: `a = { b: 100, x: { y: 200 } }`. You can nest arrays, other objects or assign functions, numbers or strings to each property. With proper indentation this way of defining a complex structure can be very clear.

Comment: @mamápitufo. That's a good way to do it, without initializing every object it the path of the object

Answer (score 2):

You can't exactly.

```
a.x = {y: 200};
```